# Why was this post closed as opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, opinion-based

This post got closed as opinion-based: [When should I use read.csv() versus read_csv() in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52617205/13552470). Why is that?

There are plenty of "When should I use x over y" types of questions that get highly upvoted and don't get closed: [When should I use](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22when+should+I+use%22), [When to use](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22when+to+use%22)

Comment: "that get highly upvoted and don't get closed" - **never** use old questions as a benchmark to justify why a closure was bad. We have plenty of clearly off-topic questions that aren't closed because they're old and weren't later picked up.

Comment: To be fair, the same applies to new questions. The sheer number of them means that some will inevitably not get the moderation attention they deserve.

Comment: @CertainPerformance which is also a reason why the old ones were never closed. Same problem back in the day, say problem today.

Comment: It seems there's another one [What is the practical difference between read_csv and read.csv? When should one be used over another?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60374887/15497888)

Comment: It looks like a reasonable question, and can easily be edited to not sound opinion-based. It would be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60374887 so not much point in doing that, I feel.

Comment: @cigien Interesting. Given the view counts, it appears that the wording that made the second question "not sound opinion-based" also made it harder to find.

Comment: @cigien Well, if it's reopened then it can be closed as a duplicate to redirect people to the better answers.

Comment: @IanCampbell Yeah, I agree, it can be useful as a signpost. I don't mind reopening and closing as a duplicate. In that case, perhaps the title before your edit would be better, since as AnnZen pointed out, it's possibly more searchable (and it doesn't matter that it might invite opinions as it would be closed anyway).

Comment: My question is why didn't that person ask the teacher who made the claim...

Comment: @Gimby, Perhaps they weren't confident enough to not think they wouldn't sound like a fool for asking? Maybe they are just a shy person by nature? Maybe it was a quick fly-by blurb in a slew of other useful necessary information that was only picked up on when they had a bit of a think about it or actually tried things out? Maybe the teacher vanished immediately off to their next class and there was no further opportunity (SO to the rescue).

Comment: @outflak Sure, if you think long enough you can come up with a whole list of pretty unrealistic reasons.

Comment: Whether some approach is [200 times faster than another approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-do-i-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql/22855514#comment122782799_22855514) ought to be findable on Stack Overflow, especially if it is a common scenario (that all beginners run into.)

Comment: I'm pleasantly surprised to see someone ask about my question from college haha. I felt like it was a useful question. Given that it's gotten more views than almost any of my other SO questions, it's probably something that other people have googled in some way or another. I understand the point though that it's probably a bit too subjective though. Maybe I could've worded it better, but I think I was just asking for the differences between two functions. Would rather it stays open but honestly it's whatever SO wants.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This post got closed as opinion-based: *When should I use read.csv() versus read_csv().* Why is that?

Because "when should I use X vs Y" is an opinion-based question, that's why. Unless we get more information/conditions about the scenario, at least. It's like "which one is faster? X or Y" ... it always depends on a whole bunch of things.

OP says their professor told them to prefer X over Y... we can't really speak to why the professor said that. At *best*, we can guess, and such guess questions aren't good subjective questions. Further, these two functions are ostensibly defined somewhere in the R documentation, but OP didn't bother to check there and see what the differences in implementation are, or ask a specific question about said implementations.

The question *might* be editable such that it asks a good, focused, objective question, but I don't know if that will end up invalidating the answers.

Also, the question was closed four years ago. Why are you asking about its closure now? Why not just vote to reopen it if you think it should be reopened?

Comment: "Because "when should I use X vs Y" is an opinion-based question", This is one of those unfortunate presumptive stereotypes that's based in rather harsh reality. From my time here, I'd say perhaps 10% - 15% of these kind of questions actually have technical/practical reasons that are on topic and whose answer(s) would provide a valuable informative resource for others. But the other 85% - 90% are almost universally translatable to, "tell me what do and make me feel good about it". Even for subject matter experts, this can be really tricky to distinguish. Without context, nearly impossible.